# Is it possible to get the address of the first member function of a class in c++?

Tags: c++, c++-templates

Is it possible to get the address of the first member function of a class in c++?
Suppose I have the following code

```cpp
class A {
public:
  A() {};
  int foo()
  {
    cout << "bar" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
};
int main()
{
  A().xxx();  //[2]
}
```

If I guarantee that there is only one `public non-static member function`, is there a way to call it at [2] without caring what its name is?

I know this can be done via [reflection](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/describe/doc/html/describe.html#ref_boost_describe_class), but using a reflection library adds compilation and runtime overhead, are there native methods (even for non-portable hacks) that do this?

Some additional notes:

1.`foo()` may have different types and different numbers of formal arguments, and the `foo()` function will change frequently, and the interface of each given foo() is fixed, so I can't think of a generic xxx() function (or function template) to easily forward these arguments as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76062080/13792395) said.

2.I thought there would be a hacking method to touch the actual address of a member function by its address and then to call it.
I only asked this question out of curiosity, and now I know
`member functions aren't normally implemented as part of the class, they're really global functions with a hidden this parameter, it's not possible to do get the first method of the class at runtime`

What I want to achieve is something like [this](https://github.com/old-yan/CP-template/blob/main/IO/%E5%8A%9B%E6%89%A3%E8%BE%93%E5%85%A5%E8%BE%93%E5%87%BA%E6%A1%86%E6%9E%B6.png)

Comment: Why? I'm a sucker for a good story about a bad idea.

Comment: Can you just use a constructor? :)

Comment: this is either a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) or the answer is simply "no". What would it be good for? What would you use it for?

Comment: No, or use a reflection library. Or like @FamZ said, put the logic in the ctor

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number In leetcode, I can do this so that I don't need to change the name of the corresponding member function in main() when I switch between problems,And when I need to debug locally, the reflection library will make my compilation time longer.

Comment: @NebularNoise Well then, I thought there would be a hacking method to touch the actual address of a member function by its address and then to call it.

Comment: this is a xy problem. Just add a member to each class that does have the same name and forwards to the other member function. Done. No need for reflection

Comment: member functions aren't normally implemented as part of the class, they're really global functions with a hidden `this` parameter, it's not possible to do `get the first method of the class` at runtime as the class only really exists in your source code (unless its a virtual method)

Comment: *In leetcode, I can do this so that I don't need to change the name of the corresponding member function in main() when I switch between problems* -- Get yourself a local compiler, solve the problem locally.  Don't use leetcode as your compiler toolset.

Comment: imho you are being lazy on the wrong end. Any time and effort you spend on testing and debugging pays of double and triple later. This is just not true on leetcode and similar, because they fool you into thinking programming is about writing code, submitting and passing all test cases and then turn to the next challenge, reality is different.

Comment: The hacky method would probably involve macros. `#define METHOD_NAME xyz`. But has there ever been a better example that leetcode hackers and professional C++ coders are two different animals.

Comment: You can use a function pointer to store the address of the member function and a wrapper function to call it. This approach won't allow you to call the function without knowing its name, but it will enable you to call it through a generic function pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Disclaimer:** This answer is just an extension to [@463035818_is_not_a_number's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76062080/11455384).*

---

In order to handle multiple number of arguments for several classes, you could make use of variadic templates and perfect forwarding.

Here is an example with two classes `A` and `B` both implementing such an `xxx()` member function:

```
struct A
{
    int foo()
    {
        std::cout << "bar\n";
        return 42;
    }

    template <typename... Ts>
    void xxx(Ts&& ... ts)
    {
        foo(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }
};

struct B
{
    void other_foo(const char * arg)
    {
        std::cout << arg << '\n';
    }

    template <typename... Ts>
    void xxx(Ts&& ... ts)
    {
        other_foo(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }
};
```

Which could be used like:

```
int main()
{
    A().xxx();
    B().xxx("baz");

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** This would still require to change your main depending on the arguments the target function accepts.

**Note 2:** I used a common return type for all `xxx()` functions (which is `void`). If you want to also handle different return types, maybe you could add a second (in the first position) template parameter for that purpose. But then it would make the calls in the `main()` even more specific. It would possibly make the whole process pointless since the call would not look "generic" anymore.

*[Here is an example](https://godbolt.org/z/e9xrMnx6W) with templated return types as well.*

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/x46jEKzdM  
I changed the void to auto , and it seems to actually do what I want!
Is it undefined behavior to use auto this way?

Comment: Well in this specific case it should work, the difference between the template type `R` and `auto` (before C++20) is that `auto` will be deduced, if possible, from the function contents (e.g. there can be several template instantiations, but it is not possible with `auto`). But in this case it doesn't matter since each class will have only one single usage. In other words, we could just get rid of the templates completely and directly define `xxx()` with the exact prototype than the inner function that it will call (since each class has its own `xxx()`).

Comment: I didn't understand any of what you said, but thanks, I should be able to use it with confidence.

Answer (score 0):

No,this is not possible. I am not aware of a non-portable solution, though you didnt specify the compiler and target platform.

What you can do with little effort is to introduce a member function that does have the same name in all classes you want to instantiate, then there is no need for reflection, because `main` does look the same for all classes you write:

```
class A {
public:
  A() {};
  int foo()
  {
    cout << "bar" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  int xxx() { return foo(); } // <--- add this line
};
int main()
{
  A().xxx();  //[2]
}
```

Comment: But `foo()` may have different types and different numbers of formal arguments, and the `foo()` function will change frequently, and the interface of each given `foo()` is fixed, so I can't think of a generic `xxx()` function (or function template) to easily forward these arguments.

Comment: @Kargarth I know but thats not a problem of my solution. Its a problem of your appraoch. Suppose you had a function pointer, then you would still have to edit main to call the function because you need to pass parameters

Comment: @Karagath in other words, if you " can't think of a generic xxx() function (or function template) to easily forward these arguments" then the function pointer you are asking for would be as useless as my answer. I answered based on the assumption that you can use the function pointer. If you cannot then your premise is broken.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Maybe I should have written more restrictions about the problem in the first place

Comment: @Kargath, or may be it's an XY problem. Precise your needs.